¿Que significa JEROPA?
Un usuario, al que no nombraré ha escrito en un comentario a una pregunta de SLE: "Hace poco había un jeropa dando vueltas por el sitio ..."
He buscado el significado de ese término, pero no aparece en el DLE, en el diccionario de americanismos, en el NTLLE, en el CREA o en el CORDE.
¿Existe y tiene un significado real esa palabra? ¿O es como "fistro", inventada?

Es vesre argentino. Intercambia las sílabas y tendrás la respuesta.

@Danielillo El ejemplo más famoso que conozco es la banda The Gotan project que toca musica del tango.

El vesre es argot argentino, hay infinidad de palabras, algunas creadas y otras se crean. Una de las más "simpáticas" es Zolcillonca (calzoncillo) donde además de intercambiar sílabas, también reemplaza consonantes para facilitar la fonética.

En Argentina se acostumbra invertir o alterar el orden de las sílabas de algunas palabras. "Jeropa" en este caso significa "pajero", es decir: alguien que "se hace la paja", es decir alguien que se masturba. Puede utilizarse como sinónimo de libidinoso, o como sinónimo de perezoso.

He visto videos y escuchado podcast argentinos donde han usado esta palabra con dicho significado.

Buscando en internet encontré 1:
¿Qué es Jeropa?

La palabra "jeropa" es una expresión coloquial utilizada en algunos países de habla hispana, como Argentina, México y Colombia. Aunque su origen es un poco incierto, se cree que proviene de la palabra "jeringa", que en algunas regiones se utiliza para referirse a una persona muy flaca o débil.
En la actualidad, "jeropa" se utiliza para describir a una persona que es un poco tonta o torpe. También puede referirse a alguien que es un poco perezoso o que no tiene muchas habilidades. Por lo general, se utiliza de manera despectiva.

